# C++ Retrieve the IP from a name from the DNS - LINUX 

Tags: c++, linux, dns, ip, fqdn

In my C++ Linux application: how can I get the IP referring to a name from a DNS?

Please attach code sample.

10x

Comment: getnameinfo(3) is the standard C entry point, it ought to work in C++ with the appropriate incantations.

Answer (score 4):

Use getaddrinfo(). Documentation and examples [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo).

Answer (score 0):

With the function gethostbyname.

Please, search in google.

Comment: DESCRIPTION
       The gethostbyname*() and gethostbyaddr*() functions
       are obsolete.  Applications should use
       getaddrinfo(3) and getnameinfo(3) instead.

Comment: @sanold, how to use getnameifo for this case?

Comment: gethostbyname return only static IP

Comment: The DNS system does not distinguish between static or not-static.